# OneDrive failing with Location Not Available after changing user directory

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, onedrive, home-directory

I've just gotten a replacement Surface 5 after my Surface 4 failed under a "flickergate" scenario. OneDrive was initially awesome to sync up a bunch of settings I had on my previous machine, however, due to the combination of my first initial and last name, it ended up as `C:\Users\pchit`, which, frankly (and perhaps vainly) I just don't like. Especially since I plan to use this machine to show live demos at conferences and workshops, I decided to figure out how to rename my user and home directory to "peter".

I followed one of the many sources of how to do this such as this [video](https://youtu.be/w5N2aaiToiQ), which seemed to address it, except for that "handy" OneDrive sync feature.

To my chagrin, I found OneDrive showing a `Location Not Available` error each time I logged on indicating the drive path of `C:\Users\pchit\OneDrive\Desktop` as the source of the problem. Also, all my saved desktop shortcuts and pinned toolbar items disappeared.

How can I fix this so that the linked OneDrive shortcuts don't blow up my desktop experience?

Answer (score 3):

The trick, I discovered was in the registry. According to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2936105/operation-to-change-a-personal-folder-location-fails-in-windows), you need to edit some Explorer settings.

For me, by going to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders** I found a number of entries that used the *OneDrive* file paths.

```
Desktop     : C:\Users\pchit\OneDrive\Desktop
My Pictures : C:\Users\pchit\OneDrive\Pictures
etc.
```

Once I replaced all of these to my new home folder location (and relaunched the explorer.exe process), I was good to go. At least, so far, so good.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot . i too had the same issue and all my desktop icons had vanished after chaning my location from external hard drive to one of the drive in my laptop. even after changing the location from external hard disk to laptop it was showing my hard drive D unavailable. and alll the desktop icons vanished. i followed the registry edit as described above and it worked finally

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1155739)